# Netbeans Web Service Client not found

Tags: netbeans, webservice-client

I've always used eclipse before, but I'm using Netbeans for the first time because of it's integration with Web Service clients.

However, after following multiple tutorials, the way to add a web service client is to:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/flower_swing.html

1. Make a new project
2. Right click on your project, New->Other->Other->Web Service Client

However, I do not have the web service client option available, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the net beans version you have. You should use newer version of the IDE to use latest features.

Answer (score 0):

For other developers who will face this problem like me, I will leave my answer here.
I'm currently using Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0 and it's in `Web Services` -> `Web Service Client`. If you still cannot find it, just use filter feature. I found it with filter.